# Unity - Read pixels of camera into memory

Tags: c#, unity, screenshot

I am trying to develop a bot in a Unity game that takes actions based on the image produced by the camera.

I have attached a camera to the "face" of the bot, which is the camera I need to get the image of. For instance in the following picture I have run the bot and taken a screenshot. For every frame update I need to read the pixels that would be shown on the screen into memory.

How do I do that?

[image: Image description]
Ultimately I would like the bot to run in batch mode without graphics if possible, as this would speed up the process of evolving the bot.

Is it possible to read the pixels that a given camera would have shown on the screen even without graphics enabled? If so how?

Comment: Is this an academic exercise in image recognition and machine learning? When your goal is just to create an efficient bot it would be far, FAR easier to just access the game objects directly.

Comment: @Philipp Yes it is. The bot need not to be efficient, but evolving neural networks can take quite a while, so I want to do everything I can to speed up this process.
Since it is an exercise in image recognition we can not acces the game state directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your camera render to a [render texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html). You can then extract the bitmap-data from it by copying the renderTexture to a Texture2d:

```
// assumes you have your RenderTexture renderTexture
Texture2D tex2d = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
tex2d.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
tex2d.Apply();
```

and then access individual pixels with [`tex2d.GetPixel(x, y)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) or in bulk with [`tex2d.GetPixels()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) or [`tex2d.GetPixels32()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html) .